# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topic'

Tags: python, django

while i was adding value to a query set i got this this error.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):

        topic=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic

class Webpage(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):

        topic=models.ForeignKey(Topic)
        name=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
        url=models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):

        name=models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
        date=models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)



#t=Topic(topic="shoaib")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topic'
```

Comment: Why are you putting the fields in the `__init__` method?

Comment: else i m getting error in migration

Comment: Then you might want to formulate a question regarding that error as this is just going to compound issues... and without knowing the underlying error and why you're trying to do this - it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 5):

You should not redefine Django models **init**.
Try something like that:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.topic
```